# PHP rename function problem

Tags: php

I'm trying to move a file on my server from one folder to another using the php rename function, but I'm getting this error

> Warning: rename(/home/pramiro/public_html/new/cipri/adauga/tmp/Koala.jpg, /home/pramiro/public_html/new/images/memo/Koala.jpg) [function.rename]: No such file or directory in /home/pramiro/public_html/new/cipri/adauga/categorie.php on line 13

The paths are good, the folders exist and the file to be copied is in the tmp folder.What could I be doing wrong?

This is the code:

```
$filename=$_POST['poza_conv'];
$filename=substr($filename,37);
$old_path='/home/pramiro/public_html/new/cipri/adauga/tmp/'.$filename;
$new_path=' /home/pramiro/public_html/new/images/';
switch($_POST['categorie_conv'])
{
    case 'memo': $filename=$new_path.'memo/'.$filename;
    break;
    case 'ort_sup': $filename=$new_path.'ort_sup/'.$filename;
    break;
}

rename($old_path,$filename);
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your mistake:

```
$new_path=' /home/pramiro/public_html/new/images/';
```

There is a leading space just before `/home`, which is causing the error, so it should be:

```
$new_path='/home/pramiro/public_html/new/images/';
```

If you *still* get the error, then the next most likely culprit is, as others say, permissions, particularly on the directories you are moving the file between, and the file itself.

Answer (score 3):

Permissions maybe? The PHP script probably doesn't run under your own user account, and if the PHP user doesn't have permission to read the files, PHP won't see them.

Comment: So what permissions should I use?

Comment: You should chmod files to 777

Comment: The php or the images?Or both?

Comment: If any, the images. A better solution however, especially on a shared host, would be to give the PHP user (`www-data` for a typical LAMPP box) access to them, either through a group, or by making it the owner.

Answer (score 0):

Does the destination path `/home/pramiro/public_html/new/images/memo/` really exist?  The error suggests it does not.

Comment: It exists!even tryied echo getcwd();

Comment: @Vidi: you should be checking using `is_dir($new_path);` instead of `getcwd();`.